# little squares instead of greek letters

Tags: greek, letters

I don't understand why everytime I write greek letters in my text they are not recognized by the interface and instead it is visualized a square for each letter. In the output everything is fine. Hebrew letters are correctly visualized.
I'm using \textgreek{}. The problem occur when I paste greek text taken from the online dictionary or similar. But for instance if I paste the letter pi it is visualized correctly.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What interface?

Comment: Even if your TeX engine is able to render the glyphs in the pdf, maybe you don't have a greek font installed on your machine , your “interface” can access?

Comment: It’s possible that you’re using a font in your editor that has π but not other Greek letters. Can you change it to, for example, DejaVu Sans Mono?

Comment: I have several greek fonts installed on my pc. I use winedt as interface.

Comment: I changed the font to DejaVu Sans Mono and it worked, but the font is ugly. I used Maiandra GD. Are there some other usable fonts that visualize greek letters correctly?